# github action get actual commit date

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to develop a github action. In the github action, I am trying to fetch the date when a particular file was committed. I run the following command:

```bash
git --no-pager log -1 --format=%ad -- "dir/file.py"
```

This returns the today's date, but I know that I committed that file two days back.
Any idea how to do that?

In essence, I am trying to get the latest actual commit date of a file.

Comment: The command seems correct to me, you may have an extra commit there or something. Try investigating with doing something like `git log -3 dir/file.py`.